# Can we make 1 UIButton for 2 action with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, select, uibutton, action

i want to make 2 action for a button like that.
selected and deselected action for 1 button.

```
   @IBAction func btntouch(sender: UIButton) {

         if firsttouch
        {
         print bla bla
         change button to selected style. maybe background color. 
         }
      else
        {

        }
}
```

how can i do that?

Comment: What are your condiitons ?

Comment: Take a look at touchDown event, but not sure if you can use the same method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you need to split two button statuses - like ON and OFF, try this:

```
var buttonSwitched : Bool = false

@IBAction func btntouch(sender: UIButton) {

    //this line toggle your button status variable
    //if true, it goes to false, and vice versa
    self.buttonSwitched = !self.buttonSwitched

    if self.buttonSwitched
    {
        //your UI styling
    }
    else
    {
        //your opposite UI styling
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create 2 `IBActions`:

```
@IBAction func touchDown(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("down")
}

@IBAction func touchUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("up")
}
```

When connecting the first one, make sure the `event` is set to `touchDown`. For the second one, make sure it is set to `touchUpInside`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Depending on your requirements, you could store the current state of the button in the view controller or in the model.

If the visual change caused by the first touch needs to be persisted across opening and closing of your view controller, store the value indicating the change in the model; if you need to reset the visuals when the view controller shows, store the value in the view controller itself:

```
var firstTouch = true
@IBAction func btntouch(sender: UIButton) {
     if firstTouch  {
         firstTouch = false
         ...
     } else {
         ...
     }
}
```